# Complexity of Integer Division

Tags: complexity-theory, arithmetic, integers

My favourite algorithm textbook: The Algorithm Design Manual S. Skiena.pdf
had this interesting problem:

> 1-28. [5] Write a function to perform integer division without using either the / or * operators. Find a fast way to do it.

What's the lower bound for asymptotic complexity of this problem?   `

P.S: I know repeated subtraction with `a` will work. It has asymptotic linear complexity with `b` (case where `a = 1`). However, repeated subtraction has exponential complexity with $n$ where $n$ is the number of bits needed to represent the number. Specifically it is $\Theta(2^n)$. So it is definitely not fast.

Comment: It'd be interesting to try implementing Goldschmidt's algorithm and seeing how that goes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia has a nice page about the [complexity of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations), and there is also a [dedicated page about division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm). Asymptotically, division has the same complexity as multiplication. The fastest known algorithm, due to [Harvey and van der Hoeven](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778), runs in time $O(n\log n)$. However, this algorithm isn't practical (it is not fast in practice, since the integers aren't large enough). Wikipedia lists [no known lower bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Lower_bounds), though some people believe that the complexity should be $\Omega(n\log n)$, and there are some bounds in weak models. See for example [Lower Bounds for Multiplication via Network Coding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10935) by Afshani, Freksen, Kamma, and Larsen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer the author has in mind is something more in the line of binary long division, which can be "efficiently" implemented with shifts, subtractions and comparisons in $O(W)$ steps where $W$ is the machine word length in bits.

Notice that using bit shifts, which could be interpreted as a way to reintroduce multiplication thru the back door, is not a necessary condition to obtain an algorithm linear in $W$ given that they can in turn be substituted by iterated doubling of the dividend,

```
const int W = 8*sizeof(int);
int p2w[W];
p2w[0]=p;
for (int w=0; w<W-1; ++w)
    p2w[w+1]=p2w[w]+p2w[w];
```

which can generate all the necessary elements in the sequence ${2^w p}$ for $0\le w \le W$ also in linear time, at the cost of $O(W)$ extra memory.

We can then divide $q=a/p$ using no more than $O(W)$ operations as follows:

```
int q=0;
for (int w=W-1; w>=0; --w) {
    q+=q; // same idea as before
    // binary long division
    if (a>p2w[w]) {
        a-=p2w[w];
        ++q;
    }
}
```

This analysis obviates the complexity and delay of the digital circuits implemented in hardware and assumes addition and the other instructions run in constant time. A more sophisticated analysis could take into account the combined algorithmic+circuit complexity by counting the total number of gates and the cycles necessary to execute the solution, which is similar to the concept of PDP (power-delay product) in electronic engineering.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have a multiplication operation, you can implement for example a 64x64 bit product with 63 additions, in constant time. So your asymptotic behaviour doesn’t change.